# Problems with append using a for loop involving lists in Python 2

Tags: append

I'm a beginner with python 2 and I've got two problems with 'append' command using a for loop. 
I'trying to make run this piece of code, but it doesn't work properly:

```
def pole():
    fish_pole = []
    fish_elements = ['stick', 'liana', 'worm', 'bended needle']

    pick_choice = raw_input()

    if pick_choice == "pick up":
            print "Good boy. You start picking up your 'tools'"

            for element in fish_elements:
                fish_pole.append(element)
                fish_elements.remove(element)
                print "You've found a %s and then" % element

            if not element in fish_elements:
                print "Ok you have the tools you need."
                print "Now you can go to the river."
                river()
     else:
        print "Come on. The sun is dying."
        pole()
```

Ok, my problems are these:

1. I can't figure out why it prints the "You've found a %s and then" string only for the element 'stick' and the element 'worm';
2. if I write simply "if not fish_elements:" I have the first problem I've just mentioned above plus this one: as soon as the script finishes printing the two strings for 'stick' and 'worm', it goes straight for the 'else' option and it restarts the entire pole() definition from the beginning.

Please help me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're iterating through all the elements of fish_elements you can consider removing   `fish_elements.remove(element)` as it may be the main problem.

```
for element in fish_elements: 
    fish_pole.append(element)
    print "You've found a %s and then" % element
```

Comment: Ok, so I assume I have misunderstood how the for loop works. In my mind I've been thinking that 'for loop' would have appended each element and, immediately after that, deleted the same element in order to process the subsequent element of the 'fish_elements' list. Thank you, I'll try to fix the code.

Comment: The problem is that you delete while iterating through the sequence. That's bad practice as it will fail to behave as you wish

Comment: I know I'm a "bit" late and I'm sorry for this but...thank you very much!